# Trying to select radio button based on asp variable

Tags: javascript, database, asp-classic, radio-button

Hi and thanks for your help,

I am trying to select a radio button based on an ASP variable.  This variable directly correlates to the value field of the radio button.

Any ideas guys/gals?

Thanks,
Will

Comment: are we talking about classic asp?

Comment: Yes, I am using classic asp, but I was wanting to try this on the client side (Javascript).  I will be more specific next go round.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myradiogroup = document.getElementsByName('groupname of radio buttons');
                   // or document.forms['formname'].elements['radiogroupname'];
for (i=0; i<myradiogroup.length; i++){
     if (myradiogroup[i].value == '<%= myASPValue %>') myradiogroup[i].checked = true;
     else myradiogroup[i].checked = false;
}
```

remember, radio buttons come in groups... your question does not specify if you want that in server side or client side, i assumed its client side

Comment: for (i=0; i<myradiogroup.length; i++){
            myradiogroup[i].checked = (myradiogroup[i].value === '<%= myASPValue %>')? true : false;
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the ASP Server-Side code by checking if the value of the radio button is equal to your variable.

```
<input type="radio" ... value="<%=sRadioButtonValue%>" <% If sValue = sRadioButtonValue Then Response.Write "checked=""checked""" %> />
```

Comment: Right, though for radio you want `checked` not `selected`

Comment: It should be checked="checked", not checked="true"

Comment: @mgroves Actually it can be checked="anything"... all you need in html is the keyword "checked" but to be xhtml compliant you need to have attributes equal something.  I typically use checked="checked" as well but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: not according to: http://www.w3schools.com/Xhtml/xhtml_syntax.asp - I understand that (many? most? all?) browsers don't care.  I would appreciate a citation if I'm wrong.

Comment: While it may work in most/all browsers, it is not semantically correct. I stand corrected.